# Python requests: при указании заголовков запросы по сети идут в случайном порядке

Tags: python, requests, словари

Использую библиотеку requests для выполнения запросов по сети. Но возникла проблема. Когда указываю заголовки, то они идут в рандомном порядке

```
>>> headers = {'Connection':'keep-alive',
           'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch',
           'Accept-Language':'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
           'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
           'Origin':'http://site.ru',
           'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.0 Safari/537.36'}
>>> headers
{'Origin': 'http://site.ru', 'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.0 Safari/537.36', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'}
```

Origin перескакивает в самое начало. Суть в том, что сервер восприимчив к подобным переменам, и заголовки надо отправлять в строго определенном порядке. Вычитал что это проблема возникает из за того что используется словарь. Однако как я понял, requests принимает header только в таком виде.

Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?
PS возможности вмешиваться в работу сервера нет.

Comment: OrderedDict не решает проблему?

Comment: @Fike Сделал. При выводе переменной все идет по порядку, как надо, однако при осуществлении запроса, Origin опять вырывается со своего места и идет не там где надо, сразу после Host

Comment: А можете кусок кода привести, как заголовки на сервер отправляете?

Comment: @WorldCount http://pastebin.com/ECwC2fvC

Comment: Хммм, не знаю, c сайтов все норм, ответ 200 приходит.

Comment: @WorldCount Конкретно с нужного мне сайта приходит 403 так как он придирчив.

http://pastebin.com/WnLwwsHr лог с прокси сервера, тут видно что Origin идет невпопад

Comment: @naym, беглый гуглеж сказал, что это нарушение спеки (что, в общем-то, не самая редкая вещь), поэтому на питоне нет прямого решения проблемы (хотя я в упор не понимаю, почему `OrderedDict` для создателей бибилиотеки не указ). На ум приходит только банальный хак:

    headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n...'

То есть, по факту, самому сделать заголовки сообщения. Вопрос только в том, как отнесется библиотека к CRLF в сообщении, насколько понял из спеки, их нужно отбивать пробелами, что она может сделать.

Comment: @Fike попробую такой вариант, по тестированию отпишусь.

Comment: @naym, попробуйте реализовать то же самое через httplib/urllib. Что за сайт такой, если не секрет? Если я все правильно увидел, то для инстаграма есть [sdk](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram).

Comment: Проблему так и не решил.

Решил использовать httplib

Answer (score 5):

Порядок http-заголовков не гарантирован (ни в спецификации, ни на практике). Заголовки могут быть переставлены при транспортировке через интернет. Хотя для целей [спецификации (Internet Message Format)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6) заголовки не следует переставлять в целом, а некоторые заголовки не должны переставляться вообще никогда. См. [Сохраняет ли HTTPMessage порядок ключей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575674/23044)

> возможности вмешиваться в работу сервера нет.

Чтобы упорядочить свои заголовки, достаточно их как [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) передать (так как dict в Питоне не упорядочен до версии 3.7). Если вы хотите также свой порядок для заголовков, которые `requests` самостоятельно выставляет, то можно их переопределить на Session объекте. См. [Header Ordering](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#header-ordering):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import OrderedDict
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = OrderedDict([
    ('Connection', 'keep-alive'), 
    ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate'),
    ('Origin', 'example.com'),
    ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 ...'),
])
# ...
custom_headers = OrderedDict([('One', '1'), ('Two', '2')])
req = requests.Request('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/get', headers=custom_headers)
prep = session.prepare_request(req)
print(*prep.headers.items(), sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
('Connection', 'keep-alive')
('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate')
('Origin', 'example.com')
('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 ...')
('One', '1')
('Two', '2')
```

Порядок заголовков сохранён.

Answer (score 3):

И Вы и Python и Header'ы в HTTP используют словарь {"ключей":"значений"}, не имеет никакого смысла указывать Header'ы по другому. Меняйте серверную часть, которая нормально сможет обращаться к заголовкам по их "ключу". Что это за серверная часть, у которой важен порядок словаря? Словарь на то и словарь, чтобы обращаться к значению по его ключу. И я вас уверяю, даже не пытайтесь сдерживать порядок словаря, это невозможно, при передаче данных порядка не будет. Есть конечно разного рода сортировка для словарей, но она не применима конкретно к Header'ам, так как Header'ы сами по себе сконструированы по принципу словаря.