# Сохраняет ли HTTPMessage порядок ключей?

Tags: python

Сохраняет ли http.client.HTTPMessage и его аналог в python 2 порядок ключей? Вот такой код ([ideone](http://ideone.com/4zM5ks)):

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from io import BytesIO

class HTTPRequest(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request_text):
        self.rfile = BytesIO(request_text)
        self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
        self.error_code = self.error_message = None
        self.parse_request()

    def send_error(self, code, message):
        self.error_code = code
        self.error_message = message


request_text = (
    b'GET /who/ken/trust.html HTTP/1.1\r\n'
    b'Host: cm.bell-labs.com\r\n'
    b'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n'
    b'Accept: text/html;q=0.9,text/plain\r\n'
    b'\r\n'
    )

request = HTTPRequest(request_text)

print( "Error code:", request.error_code )      # None  (check this first)
print( "request.command", request.command )         # "GET"
print( "request.path", request.path )            # "/who/ken/trust.html"
print( "request.request_version", request.request_version ) # "HTTP/1.1"
print( "len(request.headers)", len(request.headers) )    # 3
print( "request.headers.keys()",request.headers.keys() )  # ['accept-charset', 'host', 'accept']
print( "request.headers['host']", request.headers['host'] ) # "cm.bell-labs.com"
print( "type(request.headers)", type(request.headers) )
```

Answer (score 1):

***Документация*** для [`http.client.HTTPMessage`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) и его родительского класса [`email.message.Message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) **не гарантируют сохранение порядка** заголовков. [Текущая ***реализация***](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a19ae25ec0cebde2881a0f9d0f39d5ced6208686/Lib/email/message.py#L426-L460) использует список `_headers` для хранения заголовков, поэтому обход заголовков (`iter(headers)`, `header.keys()`, `headers.values()`) **сохраняет порядок вставки** заголовков.

Согласно [*спецификации* (rfc 7230)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2), порядок заголовков в http-сообщении *не важен*, eсли имена разные:

> The order in which header fields with differing field names are
> received is not significant.

Порядок заголовков [с одним и тем же именем нельзя менять](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750330/4279),  из той же [rfc 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2):

> The order    in which header fields with the same field name are
> received is    therefore significant to the interpretation of the
> combined field    value; a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these
> field values when    forwarding a message.

---

Можно считать, что намерение [`email.message.Message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) реализовать поведение из [rfc 5322 (замена устаревшой rfc 2822)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6):

> It is important to note that the header fields are not guaranteed to
> be in a particular order.  They may appear in any order, and they
> have been known to be reordered occasionally when transported over
> the Internet.  However, for the purposes of this specification,
> header fields SHOULD NOT be reordered when a message is transported
> or transformed.  More importantly, the trace header fields and resent
> header fields MUST NOT be reordered, and SHOULD be kept in blocks
> prepended to the message.

То есть: порядок заголовков не гарантирован. Заголовки могут быть переставлены при транспортировке через интернет. Хотя для целей этой [спецификации (Internet Message Format)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6) заголовки *не следует* переставлять в общем, а некоторые заголовки *не должны* переставляться вообще.

---

Вкратце: не рассчитывайте на определённый порядок принимаемых заголовков, кроме специальных случаев. Но при этом сами старайтесь не нарушать  порядок отсылаемых заголовков, если на это нет явной уважительной причины.